# How to tokenize brackets?

Tags: java, string, stack, stringtokenizer

I have used `StringTokenizer` as follows and expected it to actually separates each brackers but it took all as a token. How can I tokenize them?

```
    Stack<String> a=new Stack<>();
    String S = "{[()()]}";
    String temp="";
    StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(S);
    while (str.hasMoreTokens()){
        temp=str.nextToken();
        a.push(temp);
    }
```

Comment: *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.*

Answer (score 1):

```
// write all symbols you want here on st
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, "@!");



String s = "Hello, i am using Stack Overflow;";
System.out.println("s = " + s);
String delims = " ,;";
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(s, delims);
while(tokens.hasMoreTokens())
System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you try

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("[[]{}[[]]()]","[]{}()");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

It will return empty as it is tokenizing the string but there is nothing else left after tokenising all the brackets. If you instead try :

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("[[a]{b}[[c]d]()]","[]{}()");
```

You will get a b c d - the tokenised values.

Now if you want to leave the brackets there, id recommend lookahead and lookback regex :

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(z,"[]{}()");
String regEx "(?<=[{}()\\[\\]])|(?=[{}()\\[\\]])";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(z.split();
```

that will return :

```
[[, [, a, ], {, b, }, [, [, c, ], d, ], (, ), ]]
```